# Reuse cocos2d actions

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible (and a good practice) to reuse the same actions  for multiple CCSprites that use the same action?

For if I have 10 CCSprites that all need to be scaled. And I create a scale action called scaleAction. Is it possible to reuse the same action for a sprites?

When I tried to do that I get only one sprite scaling and not all of them. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question asks about re-using one action for multiple sprites, the answer is a clear: no.

Each sprite must run its own actions. If there's an action that's already running on node A and you're trying to run the same action on node B, the action will only affect one of the two nodes.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know is not recommended to reuse actions. You should check the following links about the same issue that you have and how they solve the issue. Best way in my opinion is go to a subclass approach.

[retain CCActions for best performance](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6630)

[Cocos2D: Reuse animation for different sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410563/cocos2d-reuse-animation-for-different-sprites)

BTW, a simple search on our friend google answer you question :)

Comment: The issue is that apparently it is not good practice to create a lot of ccsequence actions as it is expensive and reduces performance on older iPhones. I guess I will have to create custom CCAction to take care of the whole animation.

Comment: I would like to create a cartoony squish squash bounce animation and that requires a lot of ccsequences and ccspawns. My only choice is to create a custom CCAction for this.